# JavaScript varible scoping

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, ecmascript-5

```
function main() {
    a = 5;
    b = 10;
    console.log(a + b);
}
main();                 //prints 15
console.log(a + b);     //prints 15
```

**JavaScript supports functional and global scoping yet the second console.log statement prints the output 15.**
If i use var to declare the variables then the second console.log throws error.
I am still learning JavaScript coming from a c++/java background this seems very confusing.

Comment: _"...yet the second console.log statement prints the output 15"_ - Because `a` and `b` are global variables because of the missing `var`

Comment: Welcome to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Use strict mode. There **has** to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: Yes, always put `"use strict";` at the top of your JavaScript file to avoid issues like this.